# yii2-auth - batch processing API calls for all users

Tags: php, yii2

I have a function in a `\yii\authclient\OAuth2\DataGetter` model called *e.g.* `getData()`:

```
public function getData(){
  return $this->api('/user/data', 'GET');
}
```

This works fine with *e.g.*:

```
$getter = new DataGetter();
var_dump($getter->getData());
```

**But only for the currently logged in user.** I want to be able to run this for any user, as I am looking to be able to batch run `getData()` for all users, say at 3am every Sunday.

So I think I am trying to set the user ID in my `\yii\authclient\OAuth2\DataGetter`? But I have no idea how to do this, nor if this is even the way to do it. I can't seem to find anything in the docs. Is anyone able to help?

Thanks.

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-authclient-oauth2.html  `$clientId  OAuth client ID`

Comment: Not quite sure what you're telling me @ineersa - $clientId is not the user ID.